# Drawable Preview panel state selector missing

Tags: android-studio

In the Android Studio preview panel, I remember having a bar at the top when previewing drawable, where you could preview different states. I managed to find a screenshot of it somewhere:
[image: Android Studio Selector State Bar]

I think I pressed a hotkey or toggled a setting, it disappeared and now I cannot find the setting to get it back.